# Check if user belongs to an AD group .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an app where on login I want to check if the user is a part of a particular AD group or not. If yes then continue with the application, if not then show error: "I do have the LDAP connection address for the AD".

I am not sure how can we do this .NET core as there are not any examples to do so.

Comment: Try using the authorize attribute like so `[Authorize(Role="ADGroupName")]`, make sure windows authentication is enabled. If that works I am pretty sure you can use `User.IsInRole("ADGroupName")`, you'll have to see and work from there.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem and solved it by using a middleware.

1. I added to appsettings.json line with user and groups for authentication (or which ones will be authorized), example:

   ```
   {
       "AuthenticationGroupsAndUsers": "domain\\group,domain\\username",
       "Logging": {
           "LogLevel": {
               "Default": "Warning"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add a new class which will read the config and check does the current user belong to the authorized groups/users

   ```
   public class AdAuthorizationMiddleware
   {

       private readonly string _groupsAndUsersConfigField = "AuthenticationGroupsAndUsers";
       private readonly List<string> _authorizedGroupAndUsers;
       private IConfigurationRoot _configuration { get; }

       private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

       public AdAuthorizationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
       {
           // Read and save app settings
           _configuration = GetConfiguration();
           _authorizedGroupAndUsers = _configuration[_groupsAndUsersConfigField].Split(',').ToList();

           _next = next;
       }

       public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
       {
           // Check does user belong to an authorized group or not
           var isAuthorized = _authorizedGroupAndUsers.Any(i => context.User.IsInRole(i));
           // Return error if the current user is not authorized
           if (!isAuthorized){
               context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
               return;
           }
           // Jump to the next middleware if the user is authorized
           await _next.Invoke(context);
       }

       private static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
       {
           var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

           Console.WriteLine("Configuration is loaded");
           return builder.Build();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add an extension class for this middleware

   ```
   public static class AdAuthorizationMiddlewareExtension
   {
       public static IApplicationBuilder UseAdAuthorizationMiddleware(
           this IApplicationBuilder builder)
       {
           return builder.UseMiddleware<AdAuthorizationMiddleware>();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Call this static method of the extension class in Startup.cs -> Configure method:

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
       // ...
       //some code 

       app.UseAuthentication();
       app.UseAdAuthorizationMiddleware();

       // some routing 
       // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: I don't know why this hasn't been marked as answered but it is what helped me resolve the exact issue posted.

Comment: A great solution - simple to understand, logical and exactly what I needed. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

I tried something similar to the above code which I was having some issues with and then realised I could just add this code to ConfigureServices in Startup.cs:

```
//Required for checking Active Directory Group Membership
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Then in a code behind Razor page I want to restrict access to I can then add this line above the class definition:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "NAME OF ACTIVE DIRECTORY GROUP")]
```

Where `NAME OF ACTIVE DIRECTORY GROUP` is the name of the group you want to check membership for - e.g. `Domain Admins`.

This was all the code I needed in order to get this working then it uses the setting in IIS for the 403 Access Denied Page which can be customised so if a user is in a group the page is loaded and if not they are directed to the 403 error page.

I'm wondering if there is a downside to this approach given all the solutions I have found have much more code. Of course this would not be cross-platform but then I'm thinking if code is checking for Active Directory group membership them it would probably be running on IIS.